# I wrote a function that calculates all simple paths for an undirected graph, and the total weight sum of all. How do i store them now?

Tags: c, graph, depth-first-search, adjacency-list

I wrote some code that takes as input a graph (weighted) i've made and it calculates and prints all possible simple paths, and it also prints a sum of the total weight cost of each path.

I want to be able to store the paths though somehow (and their respective total weights), so I can calculate which one is the shortest.

Here's the code for this part of the program:

```
//all paths function
void allPaths(Graph* graph, int src, int dest){
    
   
    StackNode* path = NULL;
    //setting the vertices to not visited state (visited[0])
    int visited[graph->numVertices];
    for (int i=0; i<graph->numVertices; i++){
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    
    
    //recursive enumerate function
    enumerate(graph, src, dest, path, visited);
    
}



void enumerate(Graph* graph, int src, int dest, struct StackNode* path, int visited[]){
    
    
    int totalPathWeight = 0;
    //push the note that we are in on the stack
    push(&path, src);
    // set it's visited state to 1
    visited[src] = 1;
    
    
    
    //if present vertex = destination, print path
    if (src == dest){
        StackNode* temp = path;
        
        
        
        while(temp!=NULL){
            
            if(temp->next == NULL){
                printf("%d   ",temp->data);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d-> ",temp->data);
            }
            
            //calculating the weight of the path----------
            
            //setting adjHead on the adjacency list array index[i=temp->next] that is equal to the temp->next value.
            //Then, traversing that adjacency list[i=temp->next] until the element data of the list is equal to the current temp value.
            //Printing out the weight between those two.
            if (temp->next!=NULL){
                int value = temp->next->data;
                node* adjHead = graph->adjListArray[value];
                while(adjHead->next!=NULL){
                    if (adjHead->vertex == temp->data){
                        break;
                    }
                    adjHead = adjHead->next;
                }
                totalPathWeight += adjHead->weight;
            }
            //--------------------------------------------

            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("(TOTAL WEIGHT: %d)\n", totalPathWeight);
    }
    
    //perform the enumerate function for every adjacent vertex
    //if that vertex is not visited
    else{
        node* temp2 = graph->adjListArray[src];
        while(temp2!=NULL){
            if(visited[temp2->vertex] != 1){
                enumerate(graph, temp2->vertex, dest, path, visited);
            }
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
    }
    //pop the head vertex out of the stack
    pop(&path);
    //reset the visited state so we get all possible paths
    visited[src] = 0;
}
```

here's what that prints:

```
6-> 3-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: 3)
6-> 5-> 3-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: 3)
6-> 5-> 4-> 3-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: 1)
6-> 2-> 3-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: -28)
6-> 2-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: -6)
6-> 3-> 2-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: -15)
6-> 5-> 3-> 2-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: -15)
6-> 5-> 4-> 3-> 2-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: -17)
6-> 5-> 4-> 1-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: 6)
6-> 3-> 5-> 4-> 1-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: 2)
6-> 2-> 3-> 5-> 4-> 1-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: -29)
6-> 3-> 4-> 1-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: 4)
6-> 5-> 3-> 4-> 1-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: 4)
6-> 2-> 3-> 4-> 1-> 0   (TOTAL WEIGHT: -27)
```

I've thought of making another adjacency list, storing each path list at each list node, along with the total weight, but the fact that the `enumerate` function is recursive is making me confused about how to proceed and what each function should output.

Comment: You can store an array of the current graph node per the recursion depth (depth passed as an argument). When you reach the recursion limit, and the path length is the shortest, copy the node array to another 'best' array, as well as remembering the shortest path, and its length.

Comment: @WeatherVane would the depth argument need to be a global variable? I'm kinda confused about how to calculate the recursion depth.

Comment: You can pass the depth as function argument, say `int depth` and when you recurse you pass on `depth + 1`. I do usually use a global for the current path array, best path array, best path value, and best path length, but other people might frown about that.